# Update variable from another component- strange behavior angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a strange behavior on updating an angular component variable from another component.Can somebody tell me why this is happening or am I doing something bad?

I have two components header.component and home.component On ngOnInit of home.component I am calling an api and and share that response to header.component to update the value of header.component.html

**home.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  providers: [ProfileService,HeaderComponent]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _profileService: ProfileService, 
    private demo:HeaderComponent) {

  }
    ngOnInit() {
    this._profileService.getHomeData()
      .subscribe(response => {
          this.homeData = {
          this.headerComponent.setData(response.json().payload.Profile)
        },
        err => {
          alert('home data error');
        });
  }
```

**header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-layout-header",
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html"
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  profile={Name:'demo'};

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var curr=this
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log(curr.profile)
    },3000)
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

  logout() {
   console.log(this.profile)
  }

  loadHomeData() {}

  setData(data) {
    console.log(this.profile)
    this.profile=data
    console.log(this.profile)
  }

}
```

This is my log output
[image]

It is expected to have new value on `profile` variable but on logout click I can see that the value is old one.

Comment: can you show us how you initialize headerComponent variable  in HomeComponent

Comment: I updated question with initialization

Answer (score 1):

My solution will passing a reference to HeaderComponent from RootComponent '
that containing both HeaderComponent and HomeComponent and i will not make HeaderComponent injectable

**RootComponent.html**

```
<app-header #header></app-header>

<app-home [headerComponent]="header"></app-home>
```

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent {
    @Input() headerComponent: headerComponent;
    ...
}
```

after that remove any component from any providers

Comment: did you remove it from providers from homecomponent ?

Comment: I solved it by another way.Anyway I appreciate your help.Thanks